# Clickhouse subquery use attributes from main query

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I need to execute subquery with argument from main query. But when I can try to execute:

```
SELECT
    (
      SELECT time 
      FROM changes ch2
      WHERE ch2.trackable_id = ch.trackable_id AND ch.action = 'create'
      LIMIT 1
    )
FROM changes ch

LIMIT 1000
```

I get an error

```
Error running query: Code: 47, e.displayText() = DB::Exception:
Missing columns: 'ch.trackable_id' while processing query:
'SELECT time 
      FROM changes ch2
      WHERE ch2.trackable_id = ch.trackable_id AND ch.action = 'create'
      LIMIT 1',

required columns: 'time' 'ch.trackable_id' 'trackable_id' 'action',
maybe you meant: ['time','trackable_id','trackable_id','action']:

While processing

(SELECT time 
  FROM changes ch2
  WHERE ch2.trackable_id = ch.trackable_id AND ch.action = 'create'
  LIMIT 1) AS _subquery1 (version 21.3.14.1 (official build))
```

Any ideas, please. On PostgreSQL it works fine.

I have very little experience with this database. Perhaps I need to use a different approach in building my query.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I assume the subquery should be `ch2.action = 'create'`, not `ch.action = 'create'`.

Comment: CH does not support correlated subqueries. Use join or union all + group by

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a `join` and aggregation will work?

```
SELECT ch.*, ch2.*
FROM changes ch LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ch2.trackable_id, MAX(time) as create_time
      FROM changes ch2
      WHERE ch2.action = 'create'
      GROUP BY ch2.trackable_id
     ) ch2
     ON ch2.trackable_id = ch.trackable_id;
```